# PDO MYSQL nested COUNT breaks my query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, aggregate-functions, subquery

I have query like this:

```
$query = $con->prepare("SELECT `Id`, 
                                (SELECT count(`Id`) 
                                 FROM `images` 
                                 WHERE `parentId` = :recId) as `numImgs` 
                       FROM `records`
                       WHERE `id`= :recId LIMIT 1");

$query->execute(array('recId' => $recId));

$rec = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

When I do this without the nested `(SELECT Count(Id))` the query works.
If I take out the `SELECT(COUNT(Id))` and do it on it's own, it also works.

For some reason the above query doesn't work.  I don't get any errors, just no results.  However if I run the query inside phpMyAdmin, it works without any problem and returns two columns, Id and numImgs, eg:

```
----------------
| id | numImgs |
----------------
| 50 |   10    |
----------------
```

I've tested the value I'm passing, it is being correctly populated from $recId so there's no issue there.  Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what's going wrong with this?

Thanks!

NOTE: this works perfectly, but I don't understand why I can't do it with one query:

```
try{
  $query = $con->prepare("SELECT `Id` 
                                  FROM `records`
                                  WHERE `id`= :recId
                                  AND `ownerId` = :userId
                                  LIMIT 1");
  $query->execute(array('recId' => $recId, 'userId' => $userId));
  $rec = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}catch(PDOException $e) {
  dump_exception('Exception selecting record.', $e);
}
if($rec){
  try{
    $picQuery = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`Id`)
                                      FROM `images` 
                                      WHERE `parentId`= :recId");
    $picQuery->execute(array('recId' => $recId));
    $numPics = $picQuery->fetchColumn();
  }catch(PDOException $e) {
    dump_exception('Exception counting pictures.', $e);
  }
```

Comment: `$query` or `$villaQuery` ?

Comment: sorry, corrected.  That's what happens when you copy and paste

Comment: `var_dump($query->rowCount())` = ?

Comment: And also `var_dump($recId)`?

Comment: var_dump($query->rowCount()) gives int(0), 
var_dump($recId) gives string(3) "172", which is correct as the id of a record I've just inserted, 
var_dump $rec gives bool(false)

Comment: since the query is returning false but not giving an exception, I tried dumping PDO::errorInfo but I just get "array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" } " which doesn't seem particularly useful!  This is the case for prepare, execute and fetch.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the same parameter name (recId) more than once but only pass it once? If you used '?' as placeholders then you would need to pass two parameters in the 'execute' statement.

Comment: A good question @RyanVincent, not one I can find a definitive answer to although it looks like it should be OK.  Doesn't matter either way, if I add a third parameter, I get the same results.

Comment: @RyanVincent, your answer has pushed me towards the solution, find my comment in the original question.  If you want to put the comment as an answer, I'll mark it as correct

Comment: Thanks for updating your question with the results of your investigation. Glad to have assisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I've found the problem thanks to @RyanVincent's comment below.  Whilst I have other working queries which use the same parameter more than once without it having to be passed into the "execute" array more than once, in this case, it seems that only listing the parameter once is causing the issue. I suspect that because it's a nested query, it treats it as two independent queries and as such, one has no access to the parameters of another.  That's just a guess, I may be wrong, but it seems to make sense based on my results.  Not only does the parameter have to be listed twice, but it must also be uniquely named otherwise you get exactly the same problem. So this code fixed the problem:

```
$query = $con->prepare("SELECT `Id`, 
                                (SELECT count(`Id`) 
                                 FROM `images` 
                                 WHERE `parentId` = :recIdOne) as `numImgs` 
                       FROM `records`
                       WHERE `id`= :recIdTwo LIMIT 1");

$query->execute(array('recIdOne' => $recId, 'recIdTwo' => $recId));

$rec = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use `JOIN`s and `GROUP BY`? It would look like this if I got your question right.

```
SELECT `id`, COUNT(*) AS `numImgs`
FROM `records` r
INNER JOIN `images` i ON i.parentId = r.id
WHERE r.id = :recId
AND r.ownerId = :userId
GROUP BY r.id
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Looks like it should work, and it does in myPhpAdmin, but I'm getting the same results in the actual code :(

Comment: Is your MySQL log turned on? Take a look at the final query after it's sent to the db server. There must be some error in your PDO.

Comment: I'm using a free web host and it doesn't look like I have any access to the log :(  I have enabled logging in the .htaccess file though, but that's not showing any errors